# Is there any way to pass an undefined object as parameter? c#

Tags: c#, object, dynamic, json.net

I have a method that works with a defined data object type, like this:

```
public static ItemEdificio JSONtoOBJECT(this string JSONstring)
{
   return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ItemEdificio>(JSONstring);
}
```

Is there any way to convert the "ItemEdificio" into something than actualy vary according to the object type?

Keep in mind that this is made using the Newtonsoft library.

Comment: That´s what generics are for, e.g so: `MyType a = myJsonString.JSONtoOBJECT<MyType>()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public static T JSONtoOBJECT<T>(this string JSONstring)
{
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(JSONstring);
}
```

Thats what generics (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx) are for.

You call it like this: `MyType instance = jsonData.JSONtoOBJECT<MyType>();`